# Voronoi's algorithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Can someone give me an exact pseudo code of the Voronoi's algorithm for finding fundamental units of cubic fields? I searched the web but couldn't find it. It will be very grateful If someone can point me to some free resources which I can refer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Exact pseudocode" sounds rather like a contradiction in terms ...

Comment: Yeah, It kind of is :D, I meant something which can be readily implemented with slight moderation.